# C# Entity Framework Unique ID SQL Server Save

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I need to save same value in SQL Server when i click a button. For my need i use this function:

```
private void AggiornaVersioneCappario()
        {
            try
            {
                if (modelCap.AZCPR00F.Count() > 0)
                {
                    modelCap.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [AZCPR00F]");
                    modelCap.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('AZCPR00F', RESEED, 0);");
                    modelCap.AZCPR00F.Local.Clear();
                }
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(str_azcpr00f);
                string contents;
                while ((contents = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
                {
                    AZCPR00F verCap = new AZCPR00F();
                    verCap.CPRVER = contents.Substring(1, 5);
                    verCap.CPRDDE = contents.Substring(7, 8);
                    verCap.CPRDSC = contents.Substring(16, 8);
                    modelCap.AZCPR00F.Add(verCap);
                }
                modelCap.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

When I do it the first time, also with the table populated, all works fine. 
The problem is when i click for the second time in the same session i have this exception:

> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since entities were loaded. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=472540 for information on understanding and handling optimistic concurrency exceptions.

I read the references but I can't solve my problem that occurs to the add and not to savechange. Thanks to all

Comment: btw. I would love to work with 'Entitty' Framework sometime ;-)

Comment: What is the command for do it in Windows Form?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169970/how-do-i-refresh-dbcontext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to refresh your DbContext. Looks like you are not closing your stream reader:

```
private void AggiornaVersioneCappario()
{
    try
    {
        if (modelCap.AZCPR00F.Count() > 0)
        {
            modelCap.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [AZCPR00F]");
            modelCap.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("DBCC CHECKIDENT('AZCPR00F', RESEED, 0);");
            modelCap.AZCPR00F.Local.Clear();
        }
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(str_azcpr00f);
        string contents;
        while ((contents = reader.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            AZCPR00F verCap = new AZCPR00F();
            verCap.CPRVER = contents.Substring(1, 5);
            verCap.CPRDDE = contents.Substring(7, 8);
            verCap.CPRDSC = contents.Substring(16, 8);
            modelCap.AZCPR00F.Add(verCap);
        }
        modelCap.SaveChanges();
            reader.Close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }
}
```