# EF Code First: Only set the foreign key(ID) and get a null collection of navigation property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, code-first

Thanks for the replies, to be more clare, i have re-orged my question as follows:

```
 public class App
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public virtual IEnumerable<Build> Builds { get; set; }
}

public class Build
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid AppId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AppId")]
    public virtual App App { get; set; }
}


public class TestContext : DbContext
{
    public TestContext() : base("name=DefaultConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<TestContext>(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<TestContext>());
    }

    public DbSet<App> Apps { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Build> Builds { get; set; }
}
```

Step 1> Save Data

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (TestContext context = new TestContext())
        {
            var id = Guid.NewGuid();
            App app = new App() { Id = id };
            Build build = new Build()
            {
                Id = Guid.NewGuid(),
                AppId = id
            };
            context.Apps.Add(app);
            context.Builds.Add(build);
            context.SaveChanges();;
        }

    }
}
```

Step 2> Get Data

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (TestContext context = new TestContext())
        {
            var builds = context.Apps.FirstOrDefault().Builds;
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

The var builds get a null value, while i check database, the foreign key value is well saved.

Comment: what is your `EF query` for that ? put that code also.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is set up. Is there a reason You have your Build table represented by a class named `App`? Is that just a typo? Then what's AppBuild?

Comment: a simple query
>> app.Builds

Comment: @Ksib, not a typo, just want to do some test, i have updated my question, now it is more clare, thanks

Comment: To be honest, I'm not sure how your Step 1 is saving anything to the database. Should be `context.App.Add(app);` before your `.SaveChanges()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's probably that your local EF hasn't been refreshed with App's new collection. You may need to refresh the App object from your database.

[How to Refresh DbContext](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169970/how-do-i-refresh-dbcontext)

Comment: wantna to know whether only set the AppId property in Build object works? i have restarted VS servral times, still not work

Comment: Setting the AppBuild.AppId and then persisting that object to the database should allow you to query the App.Builds property. The key, though, is that you need to save the changes to your database, and then refresh your data. Restarting Visual Studio will not do anything.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are using eager loading and haven't specified an [`Include()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx) for that property (likely), which would look something like

```
context.Apps.Where(...).Include(a => a.Builds).ToList()
```

or you are using explicit loading and haven't called [`Load()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx#explicit) (less likely).

Comment: App app =  new App(){ id = 1 ... };
Build build =  new Build { .. AppId = 1}
var builds = app.Builds();
and builds = null;

Comment: That's not a query. That's just code constructing your object graph.