# How to refresh context in EF6?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-6

I have two windows. They have separate `DbContext` objects.

Window1 is for data view.

Window2 is a dialog window for data editing.

After I edit data in Window2 - I'm using `ctx.SaveChanges()` method.

Window2 data part view:

```
    <Button Name="SaveChanges" Click="SaveChanges_Click">Save</Button>
    <DataGrid Name="ListBoxLayouts"> <!-- "ListBox" in a name from the past -->


    </DataGrid>
```

Code behind:

```
    public Window2(ref MyContext context)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        ctx = context;

        ctx.Layouts.Load();
        ListBoxLayouts.ItemsSource = ctx.Layouts.Local;

    }



    private void SaveChanges_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        System.Console.WriteLine(ctx.SaveChanges());

        this.DialogResult = true;
        this.Close();
    }
```

When Window1 gets `DialogResult` from Window2 - I'm trying to refresh data view by disposing and creating new Window1 context

```
ctx.Dispose();
ctx = new MyContext();

Layouts l = context.Layouts.Where(a => a.LayoutId == 1).First();
```

and I'm getting old version of data.

**What is wrong with my code?**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I Refresh DbContext](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18169970/how-do-i-refresh-dbcontext)

Comment: You've two variable names ctx and context, do they refer to the same object context you're working on?

Comment: @IslamYahiatene Nope. They refer to diffrent context objects.

Comment: @IslamYahiatene Now I changed my code, I'm referring to one context in whole application and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you post the code where you edit the data in Window2?

Comment: @BradfordDillon I have added code.

Answer (score 4):

You can use like this.Then no need to dispose it manually.It's automatic.

```
 using (var ctx = new MyContext())
        {
           //your code
        }
```

You can read more about context handling using below articles.

[**Working with DbContext**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj729737.aspx)

[**Managing DbContext the right way**](http://mehdi.me/ambient-dbcontext-in-ef6/)

Comment: But what if I want to bind something to that context? I have datagrid that has `ItemsSource = ctx.Layouts.Local`.

Comment: you have to use correct `context` object inside the `using` statement as shown above.Then it'll correctly `bind` and `dispose` the `context`.You don't need to handle it manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is with your binding of the `Layout` data rather than reloading the context. You might not actually be saving your changes because the data isn't bound correctly.

Judging by method names I am assuming you are using WinForms. As such, try the following.

Add `using System.Data.Entity` then try

```
ListBoxLayouts.ItemsSource = ctx.Layouts.Local.ToBindingList();
```

[Source](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg696248(v=vs.113).aspx)